# How can I open a frameless window using Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to do so anymore, after the recent updates to Chrome, which deprecates Chrome Apps?

Comment: No, it's not possible. But you can open the popup programmatically via chrome.browserAction.openPopup(callback)

Comment: @wOxxOm Can you? In which Chrome version? It doesn't show in the [specs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), and I can't make it work in my extension...

Comment: It think it requires a user gesture to activate.

Comment: @wOxxOm It only works for Firefox as [browser.browserAction.openPopup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/openPopup)

Comment: Ah, it works only in Chrome dev/canary and requires chrome://flags/#extension-apis flag.